# Program has stopped working in C

Tags: c, function

I have a project that consists on creating a complex calculator. I have already done it but i didn't use functions (I had no knowledge of them untill halfway finished). I want to remake the project using only functions, and the only thing on my main() would be me linking to external functions. I was beggining and i encontered a problem, the program keeps on not responding. My goal was to remove all the blank spaces from the typed string, so i used `"%[^\n]%*c"` on my scanf. I have no idea why it's not working and I'd like some help. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char espaco(char equacao[]){
    int i=0,j=0;
    char x[40];
    for(i=0;i<40;i++){
        if(equacao[i]!= ' '){
            x[j]=equacao[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return x[40];
}
int main()
{
    char equacao[50];
    char x[50];
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",&equacao[50]);
    x[40]=(espaco(equacao[50]));
    printf("%s",x[40]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code appears to have a lot of opportunities to overrun array bounds.

Comment: First step is to enable compiler warnings and fix them. For example the argument for `scanf` should be `equacao`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I think that's the case. We can't use dynamic arrays on this project, so I had to set a limit. Thank You.

Comment: @WeatherVane, so i don't set the [40] when i'm scanning the array? I'll redo my code then, thank you.

Comment: "I don't know how to write good code satisfying my constraints" is an *understandable* reason for writing bad code, but rarely an *acceptable* one.  Whether you can use dynamic allocation doesn't really factor in to whether you can ensure that you do not overrun the bounds of your arrays.

Comment: Judging from the way you are using arrays, I guess your intention is to return an entire array from the function and assign that to the array in `main` with `x[40]=(espaco(equacao[50]));`. Arrays, and functions, do not work like that, I recommend some background reading.

Comment: when call any of the `scanf()` functions using a '%s' or '%[..]' format specifier, always include a max characters modifier on the format specifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer,  because a) to allow for the NUL char that will be automatically added to the end of the input and b) to avoid overrunning the input buffer.   Note: overrunning the input buffer results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers. (like 40 and 50) 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names and use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: this line: `x[40]=(espaco(equacao[50]));` will try to place 'something' at the 41st location in the `x[]` array. And is only passing a single character (the 51st character to the sub function.   One suggestion to fix that is: `strcpy( x, espaco(equacao) );

Comment: this line: `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",&equacao[50]);` is trying to put the input into the equacao[] array, starting at the 51st position (which is beyond the end of the array) .  Suggest: `scanf("%39[^\n]%*c",&equacao);`

Comment: this line: `printf("%s",x[40]);`  has a couple of problems 1) `x[40]` is selecting a single character, but `%s` is expecting a pointer to a NUL terminated string.  (and note: the sub function only filled the array from x[0] to x[39], so x[40] is beyond the end of the data.  Suggest: `printf( "%s\n", x );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a number of problems with your code. I'll try to address them below.

A copy of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char espaco(char equacao[]){   // Here you tell the function to return a char,
                               // i.e. just a single character like an 'a' or '8'.
                               // It that really what you want? Or did you
                               // want to return an array?
    int i=0,j=0;
    char x[40];
    for(i=0;i<40;i++){         // Here you loop to 39 but there might not be 39
                               // characters in equacao so this is illegal code in 
                               // many cases as equacao[i] may be uninitialized
                               // Use: for(i=0;i<strlen(equacao);i++){
        if(equacao[i]!= ' '){
            x[j]=equacao[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return x[40];              // Here you index the array with 40. That is not allowed
                               // The valid indexes are from 0 to 39
}


int main()
{
    char equacao[50];
    char x[50];
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",&equacao[50]);  // Here are two issues
                                      // 1) &equacao[50] shall be just equacao
                                      //    or &equacao[0]
                                      //
                                      // 2) You overflow the buffer if the user types
                                      //    more than 50 characters.
                                      //    Use fgets instead of scanf

    x[40]=(espaco(equacao[50]));      // Assignment to x[40] is illegal.
                                      // The valid indexes are from 0 to 39

    printf("%s",x[40]);               // Here %s means: print a string
                                      // but you try to give it a char.
                                      // However, x[40] is illegal index
    return 0;
}
```

If you really want to change the `x` in `main`, you should pass it to the function like:

```
void espaco(char equacao[], char x[]){    // MAKE THE FUNCTION VOID
    int i=0,j=0;
    // char x[40];  REMOVE THIS LINE
    ....
    ....
    // return x[40];   REMOVE THIS LINE

}
```

Comment: That was really helpfull, I will try to improve my code and give some feedback, thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Your code contains several errors. Most of them gets caught by a good compiler if you give it a chance and switch the warnings on. Here is a commented rough sketch for a possible solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *espaco(char equacao[])
{
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  // you returned local memory in the original version,
  // just as the compiler would have told you had you switched the warnings on
  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    // does not skip tabs, is that intentional?
    if (equacao[i] != ' ') {
      // we strip characters, that means we can use the
      // orignal array as the destination, too
      equacao[j] = equacao[i];
      j++;
    }
  }
  // return a pointer to the result for convenience
  return equacao;
}

int main()
{
  int res;
  // reserve array of 50 char on the stack
  char equacao[50];
  // reserve another array of 50 char on the stack
  char x[50];
  // you have only 50 places to put a character in, plus the NUL, so
  // limit it to 49.
  res = scanf("%49[^\n]%*c", equacao);
  // scanf() might have failed, check.
  if (res != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Something went wrong with scanf\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // you need to copy it explicitely, assigning it is not enough
  // Just like the compiler would have told you, if you had you switched the warnings on
  memcpy(x, espaco(equacao), 50);
  // espaco() works in-place, you can check it here
  // printf("%s\n", equacao);
  // if unsure, finish the string with a NUL manually,
  // but scanf() should have taken care of it
  // x[49] = '\0';
  printf("%s", x);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Please fix `for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)`

Comment: @4386427 I cannot see the errors you describe, please elaborate.

Comment: 1) `equacao[i]` may be accessing an uninitialized character if the input was shorter 49. Either initialize the whole array or **better** use `strlen` to find out when to stop the loop

Comment: 3) Use of `memcpy` is not a bug but it seems more clear to use `strcpy`. After all the code is dealing with strings.

Comment: 4) What will happen if the user just presses newline/enter? Try it out. `scanf` is in general bad. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @4386427 there is no need for termination, just copy the bytes, useful or not, the memory is large enough. It is a waste regarding runtime but not an error. Neither is it necessary to terminate the string before return, the trailing '\0' got copied, too, and also at the right place. That all is also the reason for the `memcpy` because we have no proper string to copy. I used `scanf` because the OP used it, checking the semantic of the input is not my problem.

Comment: @4386427 number 1 is still not a bug, actual content does not matter, it just gets blindly copied byte by byte. Number 4 is still not my problem but OP's. I cannot do anything because I do not know what, there are more than one alternatives. I also cannot use `strlen` or `strcpy` because I don't use proper C-strings at that places. (I *could* use `strcpy`, though, but I do not want)

Comment: @4386427 the memroy I access is reserved on the stack. As long as it is not initialized fully the content is unknown. In our case a part of it is initialized (that part can be 100%), so the content of that part is known, we can use it, the content of the rest of that part of memory is unknown but exists. We can access it, we *have* to be able to acess it, otherwise we would not be able to write to it. So, although the content is unknown we can blindly copy it. No undefined behaviour, all defined by the standard.

Comment: Not according to the standard. It has indeterminate value (6.2.4) which maybe a trap representation. See 6.2.6 note 41 : `Thus, an automatic variable can be initialized to a trap representation without causing undeﬁned behavior, but the value of the variable cannot be used until a proper value is stored in it.`

Answer (score -1):

you must use pointers, remember Strings in C are char arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
 char *espaco(char *equacao){
    int i=0,j=0;
    static char x[40];
    for(i=0;i<40;i++){
        if(equacao[i]!= ' '){
            x[j]=equacao[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    char *equacao[40];
    char *x[40];
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &equacao[40]);
    x[40]=(espaco(equacao[40]));
    printf("%s",x[40]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this what OP wants but at least fix: `x[40]=...` and `for(i=0;i<40;i++){` and `&equacao[40]);`and ....